# Can't connect to flask app inside a docker container from host

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-network

I’m trying to run a Flask application and mysql database by running `docker-compose up` on my computer. The flask is running on port 5000.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

The docker container is responding properly when I use `docker exec` command. But I can't get any response from the host by using the url: `http://localhost:5000`.

The `curl -X GET <url>` command is giving the following output:

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

The `docker ps` command is giving the following output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                NAMES
bffa59c471f6   customer_transaction_app   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp               customer_transaction_app_1 
ad60c2830ac0   mysql                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32001->3306/tcp   customertransaction_db_host
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

> ```
> FROM python:3.8 
> EXPOSE 5000 
> COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
> WORKDIR /app 
> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
> COPY . /app CMD 
> python main.py
> ```

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

> ```
> version: "2"
> services:
>     app:
>         build: ./
>         depends_on:
>             - db
>         ports:
>             - "5000:5000"
>     db:
>         container_name: customertransaction_db_host
>         image: mysql
>         restart: always
>         ports:
>             - "32001:3306"
>         volumes:
>             - customertransaction-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql
>         environment:
>             MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
>             MYSQL_DATABASE: customertransaction_db
>             MYSQL_USER: user
>             MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
>     
> volumes:
>     customertransaction-db-vol: {}
> ```

Both the containers reside inside a docker network `customer_transaction_default`. The `docker network inspect` command creates the following output:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "Name": "customer_transaction_default",
>         "Id": "4b5b20f503af0026a2f1ef185436c9a8e3d9c2ece690e93ece0e6b12f7821edb",
>         "Created": "2021-06-20T17:52:15.603679073+05:30",
>         "Scope": "local",
>         "Driver": "bridge",
>         "EnableIPv6": false,
>         "IPAM": {
>             "Driver": "default",
>             "Options": null,
>             "Config": [
>                 {
>                     "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
>                     "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         "Internal": false,
>         "Attachable": false,
>         "Ingress": false,
>         "ConfigFrom": {
>             "Network": ""
>         },
>         "ConfigOnly": false,
>         "Containers": {
>             "ad60c2830ac0f7e270daf03334ea8a8170200e92c2bc43492c378bd1d89cd3ac": {
>                 "Name": "customertransaction_db_host",
>                 "EndpointID": "de4597a1f58d711640f71a6169111f9842c7c5d74320825657a2518d07f36504",
>                 "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:02",
>                 "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.2/16",
>                 "IPv6Address": ""
>             },
>             "bffa59c471f6762bb802fcee37db356cf2c7a59f4f88192e3546dd10ad9dbb2d": {
>                 "Name": "customer_transaction_app_1",
>                 "EndpointID": "a3ded03e28343921d799c0efc334034028821c231e1469d4359cd387c7f43f70",
>                 "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:03",
>                 "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.3/16",
>                 "IPv6Address": ""
>             }
>         },
>         "Options": {},
>         "Labels": {}
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Can you connect to your Django app inside the container(by using the `docker exec`)? If it cannot, the problem is your Django app not started properly.

Comment: The flask app is running properly. From the container using 'docker exec' command I can get proper response from the flask app with data returning from MySQL as I send a GET request through curl. But from the host machine I am not getting any response.

Comment: I guess you need to listen on `0.0.0.0`. See [https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.run](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.run)

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to connect a server in your docker network, you should change the host in the connection string that you are using to connect Mysql to the name of the container that you are willing to connect.

For your case, you have to change localhost with "customertransaction_db_host".

Comment: I am doing it already. This is the database connection env variable. 
`DEV_DATABASE_URI=mysql+mysqlconnector://user:123456@customertransaction_db_host:3306/customertransaction_db`
The flask app is running properly and connect to the MySQL perfectly. From the container using 'docker exec' command I can get proper response from the flask app with data returning from MySQL as I send a GET request through curl. But from the host machine I am not getting any response.